# Current sourcing octal buffer/line-driver for 7+1 segment LED multiplexing?

Tags: multiplexer, 7segmentdisplay, buffer, 74hc595

I would like to multiplex 8, 7-segment LED displays with two, 8-bit shift-registers.
The required current for one segment is `20mA`. I have no desire to overdrive the leds with 8 times the specified current, that will shorten their precious lifetime.

Since the displays are common cathode, the `TPIC-6B-595` is suitable for sinking current, but I did not find any current-sourcing shift registers, so I need to use an octal buffer/line-driver. I prefer octal-buffers over Transistor/FET arrays.

The `74**541` and `74**244` datasheets are not clear about the current-sourcing parameters, to me it looks like they are only sinking and cannot handle 7+1 (dot) * ~30 mA = `240 mA`.

**This is the circuit diagram:**
[image: Multiplexing 7 segment displays]

Does anybody knows any solution to my problem?

Comment: I think you're calculating wrong.  Each gate would only be sourcing the current for one segment, so only 20mA.

Comment: Yes, but the whole device has to take 8*~30=240mA (worst case) which is far beyond any octal-buffer specs.

Comment: Majenko is right. You are wrong. The whole device only has to produce 30 mA at any given instant.  That said, 74**S is not a good way to source current. You "prefer octal-buffers over Transistor/FET arrays", but that just means you need a high-side driver.

Comment: If all the 8 led, rated ~20mA each, (7 segment + 1 dot) is under power, how can the whole thing be only ~20-30 mA?

Comment: Ah you mean the whole device current - ok, yes that can be 240 max for your arrangement.

Comment: 5 seconds doing a parametric search on TI gave me the 74AC11244 - 200mA max Vcc current. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/74ac11244.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In the "for what it's worth" category, this resource I found below lists quite a few latching constant-current LED drivers (8 and 16 bit). 
http://www.altera.com/literature/an/an286.pdf

Some of them actually have shift outputs so you can gang them together and write one long stream to the first device in the daisy chain.